# Is it possible to show animations while javascript is running

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

I have a task to sort a list of elements, which includes animating them. 
The code is something like this:

```
if(condition(first, next)) {
  first.className = 'fadeOut';
  // some manipulation of both elements
  next.className = 'fadeIn';
```

The css is:

```
.element {  
  transition: all 1s ease-in 0s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}
```

and the transitions are

```
@keyframes fadeIn {to {opacity: 1;}}
@keyframes fadeOut {to {opacity: 0;}}
.fadeIn {opacity: 0;animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in 1 forwards;}
.fadeOut{opacity: 1;animation: fadeOut 2s ease-in 1 forwards;}
```

What I expect is to see the animation running on the first element, then the code being executed and then the animation on the second element. What I see in effect is the code runs and the elements get sorted but the animations are not triggered in the sequence.
I have tried adding timeouts to get each step to wait for the next, but that didn't help.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Is there a way to get the code to pause long enough for each animation to be visible?

Comment: For starters, it looks like your if statement is missing a )

Comment: yeah, that is just bad copy-paste. I don't get any errors, and the code runs, the sort is performed. The problem is that instead of seeing each step happen separately they happen all at once after the list is sorted

Comment: You have to add a timeout to wait for the fadeout to take effect, could you provide a fiddle with a minimun example? this way would be easier to modify it in a way that works.

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/yz0a9dwq/1/